# How to retrieve data from relation model in yii2

Tags: yii2

Instead if $model->id, how to change it to $model->city_name?

```
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->cluster, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->id]];
```

Here is the relation

```
public function getCityName()
{
  return $this->hasOne(LibCities::className(),['city_code'=>'city_code']);
}
```

This is my tbl_targetcities
[image]

and this is my lib_cities table
[image]

Sample View.. Change the 2 which is the ID from tbl_target_Cities to CITY_NAME from table lib_cities.
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change `$model->id` to `$model->cityName->city_name` for `label` attribute:

`$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = ['label' => $model->cityName->city_name, 'url' => ['view', 'id' => $model->id]];`